# SaxonB 9.0 vs. SaxonB 9.1.0.8 and xs:boolean vs. xs:string type error

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant, saxon

I have upgraded from SaxonB (XSLT 2.0 processor) version 9.0 to 9.1.0.8 and my program ([XML Web Generator](https://trac.frantovo.cz/xml-web-generator/)) stopped working.

The XSLT transformation is executed using Ant. And Saxon now complains:

```
 [xslt] .../stránka.xsl:37: Fatal Error! Required type is xs:boolean; supplied value has type xs:string
 [xslt] Failed to process null
```

But on line 37 of that XSLT file there is:

```
<xsl:include href="stránka-společné.xsl"/>
```

and it is probably not the problem. It might be on line 47 where I use a property (set from Ant) in <xsl:if test="$someProperty"/>

The property is declared in included XSL file:

```
<xsl:param name="someProperty" select="false()" as="xs:boolean"/>
```

I use unicode characters in the property name, but it should work, shouldn't it? (at least it worked in 9.0). I tried to use ASCII and it didn't help.

It is also not about Ant or Java version because whether it works or not depends only on the path to JAR file (9.0 vs. 9.1.0.8).

I would like to make the application compatible with 9.1.0.8. (Or is it a bug in SaxonB?)

Versions I have used (SHA-256):

```
3cb7336b154eabfb0d78a1b9b5f7c70e15a9c790193676803fa4391b60de7ebb  saxonb-9.0.jar (working)
dc09c0e3d03609ff3c11b1e19446ca82a5f7f1bc364173b7910f2267312bd7d5  saxonb-9.1.0.8.jar (error described above)
```

Files can be found e.g. at [package.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) inside .deb files – package `libsaxonb-java` in lucid (9.0) or raring (9.1.0.8).

**Update #1**

If I remove usages of this problematic property (variable in XSLT) I got different error:

```
 [xslt] Failed to process null

BUILD FAILED
…/build.xml:39: ; SystemID: file:…/šablona/makra/diagramy.xsl; Line#: 63; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.instruct.TerminationException: Processing terminated by xsl:message at line 89 in diagramy.xsl
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Message.processLeavingTail(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.LetExpression.processLeavingTail(Unknown Source)
    …
```

Which is also specific for version 9.1.0.8 (with 9.0 I got no error). On line 63 in `diagramy.xsl` there is:

```
<xsl:variable name="souborDiagramu" select="j:vytvořDiagram(
    $zadání, 
    @orientace = 'vodorovně', 
    $kompletní,
    tokenize(base-uri(), '/')[last()],
    @src
    )"/>
```

Where `@orientace` and `@src` are missing in the source document (in 9.0 such attributes were passed to Java method `vytvořDiagram(…)` as `null` arguments).

**Update #2**

I wrote a function in Java to get type of a property:

```
public static String zjistiTyp(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return "null";
    } else {
        return o.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

With version 9.0 this

```
<xsl:message>Typ proměnné $podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů = <xsl:value-of select="j:zjistiTyp($podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů)"/></xsl:message>
```

succesfully prints:

```
 [xslt] Typ proměnné $podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů = java.lang.Boolean
```

But with 9.1.0.8 I got error `Required type is xs:boolean; supplied value has type xs:string` even if I removed any other obstacles (usages of this property) and the transformation continues if I remove the last usage of it: `<xsl:message>Typ proměnné…` (but then I can't find out the type of the property).

So it looks like that a string `false` (or `true`) can be passed from Ant to XSLT and even the propery can be declared in XSLT using this construction:

```
<xsl:param name="podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů" select="false()" as="xs:boolean"/>
```

but it can not be used – the usage of such property causes error (but only in 9.1.0.8 – in 9.0 it is working).

**Update #3**

I found a workaround for one part of the problem.

```
<xsl:param name="someParameterUncasted"/>
<xsl:variable name="someParameter" select="$someParameterUncasted cast as xs:boolean"/>
```

But this is ugly because I need two names for one parameter – different in Ant and different in XSLT. Is there any way how to pass Boolean-typed parameter from Ant to XSLT? Why this stopped working in Saxon 9.1.0.8 although it worked in 9.0?

And there is also second part of the 9.0/9.1.0.8 problem: when passing value of some missing attribute to a Java method, in 9.0 it worked and Java simply got null. In 9.1.0.8 it causes an error.

Comment: It seems more likely that Saxon is complaining about something in stránka-společné.xsl (and noting that it was called on line 37 of stránka.xsl) than that it should think it was on line 37 when it was actually on line 47.  What's in the module stránka-společné.xsl ?

Comment: Thanks; I didn't find the relevant files on package.ubuntu.com, but your repository was easier to navigate.  How are you passing the value for parameter `podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů` from Ant?  I'm guessing some aspect of the Ant interface changed in Saxon 9.1 (the Saxonica site does say 9.1 no longer includes the custom Ant task for Saxon).

Comment: You can see full source code in my [mercurial repository](http://hg.frantovo.cz/xml-web-generator/file/c1999d6bc76a/%C5%A1ablona) if you wish :-) In `stránka-společné.xsl` there is parameter declaration mentioned in the question. If I remove the IF in `stránka.xsl` which uses the property it continues and crashes somewhere else (see Update #1).

Comment: In Ant build file I call XSLT task with: `<param name="podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů" expression="false"/>`

And I am using Ant's generic XSLT task: `<xslt processor="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison">`

Comment: I'd do a quick check to see what value (of what type) turns up in XSLT for parameters passed that way from Ant, with the old and new Jar files.  (I don't have deep knowledge here; I almost always use string parameters because they seem to place less strain on interfaces.)

Comment: I wrote a function to get Object type: `public static String zjistiTyp(Object o) { if (o == null) { return "null"; } else {  return o.getClass().getName(); } }` but if I try to use it: `<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="j:zjistiTyp($podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů)"/></xsl:message>` I got the same error – so I can't even find out the type of the property. Interesting is that property declaration in XSLT is still here `<xsl:param name="podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů" select="false()" as="xs:boolean"/>` and generates no errors (just usages of such property generates errors).

Comment: I'm not going to delve into ancient source code to discover the exact history, but at some stage in the evolution of Saxon, I decided to make conversion between Java types and XPath types follow rules closer to the XPath 2.0 rules rather than the XPath 1.0 rules (i.e. slightly stricter type checking); which unfortunately doesn't help when you have something like Ant that is still stuck in an XSLT 1.0 world, and when it's using the JAXP interface which says nothing about what conversions you can expect to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Ant always supplies the value of a stylesheet parameter as a string. Saxon of course has no control over this. From your evidence (I haven't done the archaeology to confirm this) Saxon 9.0 cast the supplied value to the required type of the parameter, whereas current releases (presumably starting from 9.1) use the type conversion rules used for function calling, which are weaker than casting.

If you want your stylesheet to be callable from the widest possible set of environments, I would recommend defining stylesheet parameters that accept strings. We did the same thing ourselves (also starting in Saxon 9.1) for configuration parameters - again, Ant always supplies these as strings, so we took care to ensure that all configuration parameters could be supplied in string form.

It's quite OK to have two parameters allowing users a choice:

```
<xsl:param name="use-macros" as="xs:boolean" select="xs:boolean($use-macros-string)"/>
<xsl:param name="use-macros-string" as="xs:string" select="'false'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I responded in separate answer.

Comment: BTW: I still have problem while passing missing attribute (@src in Update #1) from template to Java function.

Answer (score 1):

[Not a full answer, but probably too much to fit comfortably in a comment.]

Your difficulties appear (perhaps correctly) to center around the Ant/XSLT and XSLT/Java interfaces.  I'd try a few experiments.

1. Try an invocation from Ant that does *not* set the parameter podporaZaostalýchProhlížečů (and restore the code that tests that parameter's value).  I predict that you will not have the error you initially reported.
2. For testing purposes, change the default value of the parameter to true (using `select="true()"` in the declaration of the parameter).  I predict again that the error initially reported will not arise.
3. Use a simple test stylesheet along the lines shown below to see what happens in 9.0 and 9.1 when Ant sets the parameter `testparm` in various ways (including, especially, the way you are setting it now).  Adjust the diagnostics to suit, and try it with and without the `as="xs:boolean"` in the declaration of testparm.  If I have understood the situation correctly, I expect that when you run the test stylesheet with Ant saying `<param name="testparm" expression="false"/>`, Saxon 9.0 will tell you that testparm is a boolean and 9.1 will tell you that the string "false" cannot be cast to a boolean.

The first two experiments should confirm that the world is not behaving in an arbitrary and capricious way (I always like to check that when debugging) and that your code makes sense.  The third experiment will, if it's successful, isolate the change in behavior for incoming parameters, and allow you to experiment with different ways of setting the parameter from Ant.  (It won't however do anything about the XSLT-to-Java interface issues you encounter with your function call.)

I hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="testparm" as="xs:boolean"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$testparm instance of xs:boolean">
        <xsl:message>Test parameter <xsl:value-of 
          select="$testparm"/> is boolean.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$testparm instance of xs:string">
        <xsl:message>Test parameter <xsl:value-of 
          select="$testparm"/> is a string.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$testparm instance of xs:decimal">
        <xsl:message>Test parameter <xsl:value-of 
          select="$testparm"/> is decimal.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$testparm instance of xs:anyAtomicType">
        <xsl:message>Test parameter <xsl:value-of 
          select="$testparm"/> is of type anyAtomicType.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$testparm instance of xs:untypedAtomic">
        <xsl:message>Test parameter <xsl:value-of 
          select="$testparm"/> is untypedAtomic.</xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The advantage of doing this test in XSLT and not in Java is that only the Ant/XSLT interface is involved, not the XSLT-calling-Java interface as well.

If it's impossible to find a way of passing the parameter from Ant that successfully results in a boolean in both 9.0 and 9.1, you may want to change the type of the parameter to string:  lots of XSLT programmers live long and productive lives using the values "yes" and "no" instead of true() and false(), and writing their tests as `test="$parm = 'yes'"`.  For better or worse, strings pass through environment boundaries better than many other types.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your template and results are: **1) Without as="xs:boolean" in param declaration**: Both Saxon versions print `Test parameter true is a string.` **2) With as="xs:boolean" in param declaration**: Version 9.0 prints `Test parameter true is boolean.` and version 9.1.0.8 fails with `Fatal Error! Required type is xs:boolean; supplied value has type xs:string`. See also Update #3

Answer (score 0):

> Saxon 9.0 cast the supplied value to the required type of the parameter, whereas current releases (presumably starting from 9.1) use the type conversion rules used for function calling, which are weaker than casting.

I understand that it is not good to rely on automatic conversion if it is not covered by the specification.

> If you want your stylesheet to be callable from the widest possible set of environments, I would recommend defining stylesheet parameters that accept strings.

In such case yes, but my program is really „Ant-based“ so it will not hurt me. BTW: e.g. `xsltproc` also supports XPath expressions in params.

> It's quite OK to have two parameters allowing users a choice

It works but IMHO it is only workaround and the XSLT template code is not the right layer where the type casting of input parameters should be done – for each parameter, in each template, again and again.

I would rather improve Ant to support more data types than text strings. Anybody interested can follow my activities in

[Bug 21525 - XSLT/param@expression used as string instead of as expression as documented](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21525#c4)

My patch adds support for these types: string, boolean, int, long, double and also XPath expressions in XSLT parameters.